# Changing Title bar theme to blue for MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I am using MFMailComposeViewController in my app, it shows a black title bar, how can i show its title bar with blue background theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
```